# How to load balance a request to external server?

Tags: php, sql-server, performance, load

I have a request(php script) in login page(username & password) and three external servers like server1,server2,server3 and how can i load balance a request to these three server?

Comment: This might be a better fit for the sister site [Stack DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).  If you agree you can move by clicking:  *Flag* >> *Should be closed...* >> *Off topic because...* >> *This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network*.

Comment: Upvote, (not for the suggestion, though it's perhaps a good and fair one) but for (I assume anyhow) not drive-by downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually first tackled with a "layer 7" (application layer) load balancer or "reverse proxy", such as NGiNX. Hallmark features of layer 7 load balancers are "sticky" connections (send the same client to the same backend server), request caching, failover, etc.

```
.
               |             _ _ _ _
     client <- | - - - - -> | NGiNX |
               |             ‾|‾|‾|‾
     <internet | datacenter>  | | + - - - - +
               |              | + -+        |
               |        + - - +    |        |
               |        |          |        |
               |   | server1 | |server2 | server3 |
.
```

Here is a [configuration guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html) for NGiNX that should help you get started.